# How to train CNN on common voice dataset

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition, librosa

I am trying to train a cnn with the [common voice](https://voice.mozilla.org/en/datasets) dataset. I am new to speech recognition and am not able to find any links on how to use the dataset with keras. I followed this [article](https://blog.manash.me/building-a-dead-simple-word-recognition-engine-using-convnet-in-keras-25e72c19c12b) to build a simple word classification network. But I want to scale it up with the common voice dataset. any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the end goal that you want to achieve? Speech recognition? or what are your labels?

Comment: My end goal is speech to text conversion.

Comment: The server for the blog article you linked to seems to be down. That makes it impossible to comment in a meaningful way. I'd like to suggest "smaller", answerable questions about concrete problems instead of "how do I do <large problem>".

Comment: sorry about the link. for some reason the link opens properly through the medium app in android, but fails to open though the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is looking at [MFCCs](https://haythamfayek.com/2016/04/21/speech-processing-for-machine-learning.html). In short, these are features extracted from the audio waveform by using signal processing techniques to transcribe the way humans perceive sound. In python, you can use [python-speech-features](https://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to compute MFCCs.

Once you have prepared your data, you can build a CNN; for example something like [this one](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2017/final-reports/5244201.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0SUKEuBxzFBIeLKsfUq0f77O_NzLVTN0rHATPiQQ8whK7D1zGVhY41ajU):

[image]

You can also use RNNs (LSTM or GRU for example), but this is a bit more advanced.

EDIT: A very good dataset to start, if you want:

[Speech Commands Dataset](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/08/launching-speech-commands-dataset.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will certainly do that. Just a follow on doubt I have is, the common voice dataset is a compilation of sentences spoken by various people. For speech recognition should I convert there sentences to words?

Comment: It's much easier to work with labeled words than with sentences; you can work with sentences using RNN + CTC-loss for example, but its very advanced. You may practice with words before! If you want a dataset with already prepared words, you can take a look to the google speech commands dataset (i'll put the link in my answer). This is a very good dataset to start.